# Brick texture does not look realistic

Tags: rendering, photorealism

So, I am playing around with a brick texture with normal map, gloss and displacement. I have also added a HDR for lightning.
However, no matter how I tweak the brick material I don't get the feeling that the bricks looks realistic. I don't know what is missing, but something feels off. Any idea what I am "missing"?

Thanks for any tips and guidance! [image]

Comment: I agree with @Robert, below, to tweak the texture under familiar neutral-daytime lighting conditions. But a lot of what's throwing this image is the lighting in your scene. For example, each brick casts a shadow upwards from a non-existent light-source..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple thing that contribute to it looking unrealistic.

- The lighting is very harsh. It seems like the light is coming from below, which results in the shadows being cast in an upward direction.
- The bricks seem extraordinarily large if the camera is supposed to be at eye height.
- The walls are extreme in both length and height, which doesn't positively contribute to realism either.

I'd suggest to develop the look of your brick material in a daytime lighting on a small plane. That way you know the material looks right, independent of scale, placement and lighting in the final scene. If the results looks good to you, apply it to your nighttime scene.